# Why are these two styles rendered different if they have the same css properties?

Tags: html, css, fonts

You can see a live demo [here](http://trufavarela.com/uruware/servicios/).

The problem is the following, the `h3` and the `title-azul mas-grande`:

```
h3{
    color:#109de9;
    font-size:28px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    margin-top:15px;
}
```

and

```
.title-azul{
    color:#109de9;
    font-size:20px;
    margin-bottom:6px;
}

.mas-grande{
    font-size:28px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    margin-top:15px;
}
```

As far as I'm aware it should be rendered the same, but the `title-azul mas-grande` is rendered smaller:

[image]

When I inspect the elements in chrome, the computed style is exactly the same except for `font-weight: normal;` that doesn't appear in the class `title-azul mas-grande`:

```
-webkit-border-image: none;
border-bottom-color: rgb(16, 157, 233);
border-bottom-style: none;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-left-color: rgb(16, 157, 233);
border-left-style: none;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-right-color: rgb(16, 157, 233);
border-right-style: none;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-top-color: rgb(16, 157, 233);
border-top-style: none;
border-top-width: 0px;
color: rgb(16, 157, 233);
display: block;
font-family: omnes;
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: normal; #This does not appear when I inspect the div with the class title-azul mas-grande
height: 28px;
line-height: 28px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
vertical-align: baseline;
width: 750px;
```

This is weird since the desired font weight is actually `normal`, but is the only noticeable difference I could find.

Can you pinpoint where the problem lies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's just an optical effect. I changed the titles text and they are rendered the same. (efecto óptico ;))

Comment: Same here, I changed the titles one way, then the other and they look identical in size and style.  I believe it's just an illusion.

Comment: If you open the image in PS and overlay the text, the "o" and "e" characters are identical.

Comment: Damn! I feel like an idiot thanks! will accept shortly!